# Removed Cloak leaves strange patterns on screen

Tags: macos

[image]

Hey there..i downloaded a software called "cloak" it lets you change the colors of your mac system .. when i changed the color it got wrong .. i tried to choose the original color but it didnt work, then i deleted the software and restart my mac but it still there.. i also tried to restore the system but i didnt set up the time machine is there any other way?

Comment: deleted the preferences file ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you do not know what I mean it is not advisable for you to mess around with those files. FYI, Mac uses something called .pref files (stored in the System Library) to save settings. This is where your problem resides.

Answer (score 2):

I went browsing in the installer package, and it looks like Cloak does some serious meddling in system frameworks.  For example, there's a `lightpurple.scpt` that does (among other things):

```
sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFileold.bin
sudo cp /Themes/LightPurple.cloak /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin
```

These are not changes that will reliably work as the OS gets updated.

You could do a search across the OS to find `*.old.*` files, but I would recommend simply reinstalling OS X.  You can reinstall the OS on top of your current system, which will replace the system files but leave your user files alone.

Answer (score 0):

Without downloading and playing with it this is my best advice...

Step one, see if it persists in another user account:

- Open System Preferences > Users & Groups (or Accounts if older than 10.7)
- Click on the lock in the lower left corner and enter your administrator password
- Click on Guest User and check the box to "Allow guests to log in to this computer"
- Log out of your user ( > Log Out YourName)
- Click on the Guest user (or enter Guest in name field) at the login screen

Step two, depending on the results of step one I would try to locate and remove it's preference file:

- If the Guest user account seemed to be ok, go to the Library folder in your user account by clicking on the *Go* menu while holding <kbd>option</kbd> and choose *Library*.  If the Guest user account looked the same as your regular account then go to the main Library folder at Macintosh HD/Library.
- Scroll down and open the Preferences folder
- Locate the file that has the developers or applications name in it.  I would look for something along the lines of com.Cloak.plist or com.Flip.plist, since the developer is Flip Conversion Design.
- Once you've found the file drag it to the trash and immediately reboot your Mac ( > Reboot)

Hopefully that does the trick for you.

Comment: Mr Rabbit,, i did what you say the guest user account has the same problem.. but i didn't find any file has the application name in it.. and thank you for your time :)

Comment: You might try booting your Mac in Safe mode, by holding the Shift key as you power it on, releasing Shift once you get to the Apple screen with spinning gear.  If the system looks ok in Safe mode then you may be able to find a support file/s that is responsible for the mess.  If the system looks the same then you'll likely need to re-install the system.